# How Skype works with background execution limits?

Tags: android, background

So, as i correctly understand - on android > Android.O we have thing, called "background execution limit". If i right, we can't run background service all time without any notifications.

But i saw, that skype, when somebody call me automatically starts. What's wrong? Whan i'm understood uncorrectly.

Comment: For sure skype receive push message and start call.

Comment: @oss i mean, that skype works fine in background, and when somebody call me, skype start automatically. How it can be with limits in Android 8+

Comment: @oss is right, I think skype uses the FCM or something like this (push notifications services). This services started by android and works in background without limits, Skype just subscribe for listening the pushes from this service, and when Skype push is coming, it starts Skype App instance with incoming call activity. Or something like that. You don't need the own background service to listen Push Notifications. You can read about it more FCM or Broadcast Receivers topics

Comment: @eugene-korotkov No need to stay in background to receive push notifications.  Application just register BroadcastReceiver and system call application when push  arrives. Application can process push notification in way that it need. For example start Activity with call.

Comment: @oss and who send this notification? I mean if i registering in Android Oreo broadacast receiver, i need to send intent to it. (so i know how to do it via services, but they cant run all time in background)

Comment: Ok, I have found that my previous comment actual only for GCM. In case of FCM application has to extend FCM service to listen push notifications in background. System do not apply background execution limits to services extended from FCM service. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Comment: @eugene-korotkov Answering your last question: _System_ push service.

Comment: @oss Thank you! So, did i understand right? Skype registering broadcast receiver on some intent. Also Skype starts fcm service, that sending intent to broadcast? 

Is it possible to make something like this without fcm?

Comment: @eugene-korotkov 
I don't know what exactly skype use GCM or FCM. 
In case of GCM application register BroadcastReceiver that receive intent from _system_ push service. 
In case of FCM application register service that extended from FCM service and receive intent from _system_ push service.  
I don't think that you can achieve something similar ready for production without these services.